# How to split a graph to minimise the length of the longest path

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

Given a graph and a number n, is there an algorithm to split the graph, by removing `n` edges, to minimize the length of the longest path/diameter ?

For example if I have the following graph:

```
A - B - C - D 
      \ E - F
```

And n = 2, you would want to cut the graph between:

- B and C
- B and E

So no path would be longer than 2. Does that make a difference also if the graph is a tree/acyclic undirected graph ?

EDIT1: changed recombining graph by tree/acyclic undirected graph

Comment: What is _non recombining_ graph ?

Comment: You first have to check that the graph can be split by cutting it n times.  This depends on its degree of edge connectivity.  Assuming that it's not larger than n, this means that the graph can be split to at least two components by removing n edges.

Comment: Do you mean, which n edges need to be removed in order to have the minimum length longest path?

Comment: You are all correct, I edited the question, feel free to edit if my wording is incorrect

Comment: The [same question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/93122/83244) on Computer Science.

Answer (score 0):

For the specific case of an acyclic graph (which I assume is what you mean by "non-recombining"), you could do the following:

1. Run the [Topological Sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) algorithm to sort the nodes.
2. Run a dynamic programming to solve your problem. The recurrence would be the minimize (US English!) the longest branch from node 0 to node *i*, using *j* cuts.

Comment: Cool let me try to implement this, never did one of those.

Comment: When doing the recurrence, it will take alot of space to store the results because at each node, I should choose to either place a cut and run the recursion with `j-1` cuts or to not use a cut with j cuts. Is that correct ?

Comment: The space required is proportional to the number of nodes multiplied by *n*. This is because, conceptually, you need to fill in a matrix describing something (the max path length) up to each node, given that you've used up to *n* cuts (DP is just an efficient way to fill in this matrix). Is that "a lot"?

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong but whenever you divide the problem in sub problems you have to make sure that the total number of cuts is equal to the input so you need to store multiple cases. This is not he same than determining the longest path for example.